# Top and bottom don't work when positioning relative using %

Tags: html, css, positioning, font-size

i'd like to know this: why top and bottom properties don't work when i move an element using % in a relative positioning? Consider this example:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  color: red;
}
```

If i use em instead of %, text will go down, why not the same thing with %?

One last thing: does the use of em instead of % when positioning elements (not for sizing them) in a fluid layout create troubles?

Comment: show us demo that doesn't work...

Comment: I posted the code, use an editor like http://dabblet.com/ to check it.

Comment: It does work _if_ you give the container a height. Without a height, 10% is a meaningless value: http://jsfiddle.net/p43yfLff/

Comment: So i need an height, thanks. But why em work?

Answer (score 0):

Because your `p` don't know wrapper div's height. Set `height` and will fix problem.

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p43yfLff/2/)

Additional info:

> It’s easy to understand the difference between font-size units when
>   you see them in action. Generally, 1em = 12pt = 16px = 100%. When
>   using these font-sizes, let’s see what happens when you increase the
>   base font size (using the body CSS selector) from 100% to 120%.

http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: Yes, thanks for code. Anyway em still work even without an height, i'd like to know why.